# Deleting the first node of a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So here's the problem. I'm trying to delete the first node of a linked list and unfortunately I'm limited to using:

```
int delete(node* head, int i)
```

thus, unlike what other threads recommend to do, I cannot return a node or use **node in the parameters. printing the set before and after deleting outputs a 0 instead of the first node:

```
//before
 12, 1, 14, 
//after
  0, 1, 14,
```

The function is designed to delete any node, but I'm stuck on the part where the header's value is equal to i. Here is a code snippet from the function `delete` which deals with the first node:

```
int delete(node * head, int i) {
   node * current;
   current=head;
   while (current){
       if((current=head) && (head->value=i)){
           head=current->next;
           free(current);
           current=NULL;
           break;
       }
...
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you `cannot return a node or use **node`, how do you hope to change the value of `head`?

Comment: my same thoughts initially. Unfortunately my assignment restricts me to use that function.

Comment: Then make the head pointer global.

Comment: @Kunal: Hint: delete the *second* node...

Comment: @Kunal I'm passing the head pointer from another class

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks for the hint. I will post the answer :)

Comment: Major flaw, unrelated to the question: `... && (if((current=head) && head->value=i)){` --> `if(current == head && head->value == i)){`

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question (and if you update the question: please don't toppost) I rolled back to the original version.

Comment: oh ok, I've seen it happen in some threads and I thought I should the same. I'll keep things as they were then.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What if there's only one node?

Comment: @zubergu: Then you have a problem ;)

Comment: You would also have a problem if the node contains a _struct hack_ or a VLA. (the OQ did not show the definition of the node)

Comment: @zubergu I have another method called destroy. I guess I can use that in that case

Comment: @PatrickBuhagiar There may be a workaround. Since the signature is `int delete(node*, int)` you can return 0 to indicate that there was only one node that has been deleted and return 1 otherwise. In the calling method you can check for 0 to set the head pointer to `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deleting the first node from the linked list, store the value of the second node and then delete the second node.

Then simply copy the stored value of the second node into the first node. And, you are good to go.

Example:

> Intitial list -  12, 1, 14

Store `1` and delete second node so that it becomes:

> 12, 14

Now copy `1` into the first node

> 1, 14

And so, effectively the first node of the linked list is removed.

Comment: Definitely did not think of that. I'll give it a try and let you know :) thanks!

Comment: brilliant, it worked! will be posting my final answer soon. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kunal What if there is only one node in the list?